# Javascript - How to load variable from a file and refresh it every 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, html

My script:

```
<?php
//header("refresh: 7;");
include 'theme.php';
ceklogin();
css();
echo '<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                    $("#show").text(
                            "I am getting refreshed every 3 seconds..! Random Number ==> "
                                    + randomnumber);
                }, 3000);
            });
</script>';
exec('/www/openvpn_wget_status.sh');
echo '<br>';
echo file_get_contents( "/www/openvpn_status.txt" );
echo '<div id="show">';
//include 'wget.log';
//echo "<br><textarea name=\"text-info\" id=\"scores\" rows=\"30\" cols=\"90\" readonly style=\"font-family: Arial;font-size: 7pt;\" >";
//$datalines = file ("wget.log");
//foreach ($datalines as $zz) {
//echo $zz; }
echo '</div>';
//echo "</textarea><br></div>";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
       var textarea = document.getElementById("scores");
       textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
      </script>';
foot();
echo '

</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

it works perfectly but what if I want the variable from a log file in my webserver, let's say the name of the log file is `wget.log` and I want to refresh it every 3 seconds since `wget.log` keeps changing as I run wget to download files?

Comment: Don't you need ajax for that?

Comment: I don't know but it already works fine

Comment: You need to call ajax and read file from server, `echo` it using php and print on browser using javascript. Make ajax every 3 seconds.

Comment: maybe this thread can help you topic tail of logfiles with php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102229/how-to-watch-a-file-write-in-php

Comment: @RaviDhoriya can you please write the script for me ? I know next to nothing about ajax. Sorry.

Comment: You can do something like this : http://pastebin.com/wHzHFzRS The ajax call is wrapped in a `setInterval` function

Comment: @hillz, check answer. I gave basic solution.

Comment: There is lot here that you could have abstracted. What a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Script to read file (readFile.php)**

```
<?php
//in this script, read any file(or do something else)
//whatever you output, it will be processed in ajax request from below script
echo "<pre>".file_get_contents( "/www/openvpn_status.txt" )."</pre>"; //used <pre> to keep linebreaks in file.
?>
```

**HTML (another file)**

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    $("#show").load("readFile.php"); //it will make ajax call to readFile.php and get output from that script and load to #show div
                }, 3000);
            });
</script>

<div id="show">
This will be refreshed every 3 seconds.
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. Never seen or used that type of ajax call ever. What request type does it use? POST or GET?

Comment: @Ravi Dhoriya my log file consists of line breaks and the line breaks are ignored once it's loaded on my webpage, how do I keep the line breaks?

Comment: @KrisztiánDudás lol on you. You should have look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/load/). It uses GET btw

Comment: @hillz then print it inside `<pre></pre>`.

Comment: Use the `<pre>` tag if you want to keep the formatting (linebreaks)